# validating string while loop logic error [Python] and csv file error

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to validate a part of my code, like this:

```
loop2 =1
    while loop2==1:
        crntCurrency = input("Please enter the current currency: ")
        if crntCurrency == 'Pound Sterling' or crntCurrency =='Euro' or crntCurrency =='US Dollar' or crntCurrency =='Japanese Yen':                   
            break
        else:
            print("sorry that was invalid, please try agian:")
```

However, I tried it again here:

```
   loop3 = 1
    while loop3 ==1:
        newCurrency = input("Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: ")
        if newCurrency == 'Pound Sterling' or crntCurrency =='Euro' or crntCurrency =='US Dollar' or crntCurrency =='Japanese Yen':                   
            break
        else:
            print("sorry that was invalid, please try agian:")



    exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    validateloop2 = 0
    while validateloop2 == 0:
        for row in exchReader:
            currency = row and row[0]
            if currency == newCurrency:
                newRt = row[1]
                validateloop2 =+1    
                toPound = crntAmnt/float(crntRt)
                newAmount = int(toPound)*float(newRt)
                print("You have: " ,newAmount, newCurrency,)
                exRtFile.close()
```

and I get stuck in a forever loop after the print "sorry that was invalid, please try again:". and if the input is correct, I get the error (I believe this to be an indentation error):

```
for row in exchReader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are several issues with your code, so let's see if we can tackle them one at time.

### Input Validation Bug

---

If you're having a problem with your program accepting the correct values, there's at least one bug in your second loop that will give you trouble

```
if newCurrency == 'Pound Sterling' or crntCurrency =='Euro' or crntCurrency =='US Dollar' or crntCurrency =='Japanese Yen':
```

You'll notice you checked against `newCurrency` for Pound Sterling and you checked `crntCurrency` for the other values. Since you read in your `input` as `newCurrency`, you need to compare against this for all values. This line should be

```
if newCurrency== 'Pound Sterling' or newCurrency=='Euro' or newCurrency=='US Dollar' or newCurrency=='Japanese Yen':
```

And [Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3456281/jasper) is correct about your code being unpythonic.

```
newCurrency in ['Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'US Dollar', 'Japanese Yen']
```

is a much nicer way to do it. Better yet, define a list at the beginning of your code so that you can use it in other places

```
currency = ['Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'US Dollar', 'Japanese Yen']
```

and then you can just use

```
if newCurrency in currency:
```

and then you can reuse `currency` other places in your code!

### I/O Operation Bug

---

Next is the issue of your program throwing the I/O operation on a closed file

> ```
> for row in exchReader:
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
> ```

the problem is here

```
exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    validateloop2 = 0
    while validateloop2 == 0:
        for row in exchReader:
                # if something
                        exRtFile.close()
```

As soon as you find your condition, you are closing your file with `exRtFile.close()`, but your for loop `for row in exchReader` is still running. So after the if statement is exited, it will iterate back through your loop again and your program will be trying to read from a file because `exchReader` is a csv reader, but you have already closed that csv file. So you have two options: (1) close the file outside of your `while` loop after you have met your valid condition and finished iterating or  (2) once you meet your if condition, you close your file and put in a break command to exit your for loop.

### Style advice

---

A few other notes on style: Why are you using `while validateloop2 == 0`? Why not just set a variable `valid = False` and then when you get your `if` condition, set `valid = True`? Then when you `break` from your for loop, your while loop will see that `valid = True` and will exit. Using a variable like `valid` as a boolean makes your code much more readable. As per my comment, you can use `while not valid:` as a while condition (assuming you have set a variable `valid = False` initially

Comment: thank u, well explained however my validation is still not working correctly the second time, and when i use 'while True' on the first one and then offer an incorrect input i get stuck in a forever loop with nothing in it?

Comment: just spotted your edit thank u, works like a charm, u clearly know what u r doing :)

Comment: Actually it should be `newCurrency` in all places in the second loop.

Comment: @user3165683, I have made a few more edits to organize my thoughts. Let me know if anything isn't clear

Comment: Thanks, @Jasper, just a typo on my part.

Comment: thank u, i have changes my validations to True loops and they work fine, however i tried to change 'loop3' to 'True' in the same format but got stuck in an infinate loop this is what i did:            while True:
        for row in exchReader:
            currency = row and row[0]
            if currency == crntCurrency:
                crntRt = row[1]
                break

Comment: In that place it actually makes sense to use a flag in the `while` loop, since you need to `break` out of two loops at once.

Comment: If you look at my answer, I actually don't recommend the `while True:` because the `break` statement will only get you out of the current `for` loop, it won't break the `while` loop too. If this is a function, you can just use `return` to leave your function, but otherwise, you still need to use some kind of boolean like `while not valid` and then set `valid = True` in your for loop to let the `while` loop know that you found your value

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you close the file and then try to read a new record. At the end of the `if`-block, you have to `break` out of the `for` loop.

But there are several other errors and many un-pythonic parts in your code:

Instead of doing

```
a == "one" or a == "two" or a == "three"
```

you should do

```
a in ["one", "two", "three"]
```

---

Don't introduce extra variables set to `1` just to get an infinite loop, use

```
while True:
  ...
```

---

```
if **new**Currency == 'Pound Sterling' or **crnt**Currency =='Euro' or **crnt**Currency =='US Dollar' or **crnt*Currency =='Japanese Yen':
```

I don't think that this is intentional, but this will be fixed with the first point.